# Sun Drying Tomatoes

Tags: tomatoes, drying

Sorry if this seems obvious, but is there a method to making your own sun-dried tomatoes or is it really as simple as leaving them out in the sun? How long should it take to reach the proper "dryness"? Once dried what is the best way to store? Any spices that can be added to complement the flavor?

Comment: Not obvious at all, good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three common ways to make sundried tomatoes:

1. Sun - This can take days.  Use a cheesecloth to keep the bugs out.  Weather is obviously a huge dependency here.
2. Dehydrator - Probably the most efficient method, but not everyone has a dehydrator.
3. Oven - Use a cookie sheet and set the oven to 140-150F.  This could be tricky depending upon the oven.  You might have to use the pilot light or prop the door open slightly.  This should take about 8 hours.

I usually store them in light olive oil once made.  I've found light oil makes a huge difference because extra virgin tends to have a much stronger flavor.

Comment: We can do them in a day in August, it gets pretty hot. You always want to cut them, it makes drying much faster. With smallish tomatoes, halve them first, then put cut side up. Larger ones can be cut int smaller pieces as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

I sun dry things by putting them in the back of my car by the rear window during the day.  The heat is intensified by the car and the fact that it's inside of something keeps bugs away.

Place tomatoes on a cookie sheet, sprinkle lightly with salt, and dry.

Comment: +1. I've done this accidentally before, with surprisingly pleasant results.

Comment: What a great idea, will definitely try.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried sun drying tomatoes with no success. It is just too humid where I live and the bugs or mold will get them before they dry.

I just slice My tomatoes in half and dry them in the dehydrator and that works very well.

If you live somewhere dry like Utah or Arizona you could just leave the tomatoes in the sun (protected from dust and bugs) and they will be zombified in short order.

Comment: to avoid bugs, make sure to cover with something mesh like a screen on top of a solid object.